# How to give role based access to a JAR file

Tags: java, authentication, jar, executable-jar, jarsigner

I have created a JAR file which allows a user to perform certain automation on application. I am giving it to the customers to try it out, so they know what they are buying.

I wan to restrict the usage of my JAR for specific user/customers, this way it will not be distributed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you could try to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107989/self-destructing-application) instead?

Comment: This is good solution given that required access to delete my JAR are available on the system where it is running.
I dont know about the environment they will be using since my solution is compatible to work on MAC, Windows & Linux.

Comment: One correct way is to have an online account system (where each user has a username/password) that is accessed by the app and requires the user to provide credentials. No login, no start of the application. To do so the online system sends something after logon that is required for the startup process.

Comment: Can I use the something like _jarsigner_ to sign the user and restrict that user to access the JAR?